# Possible problems with lower version blender rendering higher version models

Tags: cycles-render-engine, versions

I mainly use 2.83 in my work, but when I use it to render some models, there are always some messy errors. I want to ask what changes blender has made after 2.83 that make it impossible to render with 2.83, and what errors may occur when I use 2.83 to render higher version models.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are trying to render a blender file made in a higher version like 3.x using 2.8x blender.  The options used in 3.x may have improved or changed.  Try the version it was created in and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: it is pretty "natural" that older versions of software (not just Blender) cannot work with "things" made in newer versions - with the exception that it might work if you only use features which are implemented in the older version, but even then - it is not guaranteed to work so you shouldn't just do it if you wanna be safe. E.g. if you are using a geometry node which doesn't exist in the old version - what should the "old" Blender do? it just doesn't know it! Think of cars. Let's assume BMW replaces the engine with an electric engine. You can still transport people in both cars. But you ...

Comment: ...cannot use electricity to charge your old car. And by the way: the fact that you cannot charge is not an error...

Comment: ...and to add to what @Chris said, you didn't even tell us which "higher version" you mean. There have been many versions since 2.83 up to now, do you expect a list of every feature that has been implemented since then that might or might not make problems with rendering? And for all possible scenes? I mean, there not only was the change from _Cycles_ to _Cycles X_, but even other things... a default cube with a default material and a point light might be less problematic to render in old versions then complex  materials, rigid bodies, cloth, smoke, water simulations...